# Drupal - CCK or Webforms?

Tags: drupal, module, cck, drupal-webform

I've been doing some reading and I'm still not sure which module to use to get the results I want. I'm looking to build a Patient form and when the form is submitted the results show up in a layout. Here's an image example of what I'm looking to accomplish: http://mjyes.com/images/form-example.jpg

If the Patient information needs updating, then I can visit the form again and update any given field and re-submit for updating.

I'll probably need to access the Patient's information through out the web application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you've described, you probably want to use CCK. CCK will allow you to create a patient content type, customized with the fields you need.

Webform is primarily for things like contact forms or surveys where the submissions don't become part of the content on the site.